# How to find USA Water Hardness shapefiles?

Tags: geospatial

I want to find USA water hardness shapefiles. I have searched for it from here: https://www.epa.gov/waterdata/waters-geospatial-data-downloads but without success. Is there any good data source from where I can download these boundaries?

Comment: Does it have to be shapefiles

Comment: @nmtoken Yes,  that should be a shapefile